# Using 2 nested asynchronous threads - Android Java AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, nested

I've been working on creating a dynamic `AutoCompleteTextView`, and encountered a problem using two nested asynchronous threads.

The first asynchronous thread is a `Filter`, and inside this thread I make HTTP calls asynchronously. That causes the filter to return empty `FilterResults` because Filter doesn't wait for asynchronous HTtP calls.

To overcome this situation I used a flag, and used a while loop inside the filter just before the `return` line waiting for asynchronous HTTP calls to finish and set the flag.

- This worked fine, but is there a better solution?
- Can this approach lead to another problem that I can't see?

Comment: If filter works on the main thread, making it waits for the background thread to finish is a terrible idea, bad practise etc. and eventually may end up in ANR error.

Comment: performFiltering is called in the background thread so you can call sync http request,  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering(java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using JSON requests asynchronously, so I overcome this situation by using synchronous JSON requests like following:

```
RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
itemReq = new JsonObjectRequest(url + city, new JSONObject(), future, future);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(itemReq);
```